# Link click causing page to reload, sometimes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm facing an issue- A relevant amount (10%) of users on my landing page who click the button leads into either the page reloading (probably href becomes null) or nothing happens at all. I can confirm this from the data collected from Google Analytics, and screen recordings from Hotjar.

[GIF](https://s5.gifyu.com/images/ezgif.com-video-to-gif11a180cfc3f4abdc.gif) of button click captured from screen-recording. You can see in the GIF that instead of redirecting to the offer_url, nothing happens.

I'm dynamically adding the link to the href attribute using javascript, which looks like this. As this is a part of the marketing campaign, I need to pass the UTM parameters of the landing page to offer_url.

```
var s = "";
        var p = "";
        var ph = "";
        var phone = "";
        var offer_url = "http://www.example.com/click";

        var s = getUrlParameter('source');
        var p = getUrlParameter('p');
        var ph = getUrlParameter('ph');
        var phone = getUrlParameter('phone');

        if (s != "undefined" && s != "") {
            source = s;
        }
        if (p != "undefined" && p != "") {
            phone_p = p;
        }
        if (ph != "undefined" && ph != "") {
            phone_ph = ph;
        }
        if (phone != "undefined" && phone != "") {
            phone = phone;
        }


        if (source && phone_p) {
            offer_url = "http://www.example.com/click&s1=" + source + "&s3=" + phone_p;
        } else if (source && phone_ph) {
            offer_url = "http://www.example.com/click&s1=" + source + "&s3=" + phone_ph;

        } else if (source && phone) {
            offer_url = "http://www.example.com/click&s1=" + source + "&s3=" + phone;
        } else if (source) {
            offer_url = "http://www.example.com/click&s1=" + source;
        }
    function myoffer_url() {
      document.getElementById("button_final").href = offer_url; // "javascript:void(0);"
    }
    function onclick_button_final() {
      document.getElementById("button_final").innerHTML = 'Claim Your Prize <img src="./image/loader.gif"/>';
    }
```

I added loader animation next to the button as I don't want users to keep clicking in case they aren't redirected to the URL.

And this is the anchor tag (HTML).

```
<a id="button_final" onClick="javascript:onclick_button_final();" style="display: inline-block; background-color: #8BC34A;font-size: 18px; padding: 18px 44px">Claim Your Prize</a>
```

Comment: do you have js attached to the button?  or is the href always there?

Comment: I believe that there is a js attached to this link, check this id in your code to see if there are any other references to it.

Comment: Yes, there is js

`jQuery("#gosub2").attr('href',offer_url);`

Comment: Probably `offer_url`is null or empty on occasion - or the user clicks the link before the url is added - perhaps hide the link until the js is ready and then show it and add the link at the same time

Comment: Hi @Pete, this looks like it could help, could you tell me exactly how I can hide the link until js gets ready?

Comment: Add a class to it that hides it and then you can call `jQuery("#gosub2").removeClass('hidden').attr('href',offer_url);`

Comment: Hi @Pete, I added more context to the question, see if it can help.

Comment: not sure how that works at all as you never call `myoffer_url`

Comment: It gets called at the beginning of body tag like  `<body onLoad="myoffer_url()">`